# Как сделать десятиугольник в Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();
for ( var i = 0, l = objects.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
var phi = Math.acos( -1 + ( 2 * i ) / l );
 var theta = Math.sqrt( l * Math.PI ) * phi;

      var object = new THREE.Object3D();
      spherical.set(1000, phi, theta );
      object.position.setFromSpherical( spherical );
      vector.copy( object.position ).multiplyScalar( 2 );
      object.lookAt( vector );
    }
```

Этот код описывает круглую сферу three.js. Как сделать из этого десятиугольник (decagon) ?

Comment: Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.

Comment: По заданию могу предложить идею- постройте сначала правильный пятиугольник, потом еще раз постройте пятиугольник, начав с противоположной стороны окружности

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [`THREE.CircleGeometry()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/geometries/CircleGeometry):

```
var decagonGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 10); // первый аргумент - радиус, второй - количество радиальных сегментов.
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(decagonGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "blue"}));
```

Если вдруг возникнет надобность сделать просто контур, то для обычной геометрии подходит вызов `.shift()` на массиве вершин:

```
var decagonGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 10);
decagonGeom.vertices.shift();
var contour = new THREE.LineLoop(decagonGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"}));
```

При необходимости поставить объекты в формацию "десятиугольник" можно использовать метод `.applyAxisAngle()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var radius = 5;
var rotVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, radius, 0);
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
var angleStep = THREE.Math.degToRad(36); // 1/10 of 360
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: Math.random() * 0x777777 + 0x777777
  }));
  mesh.position.copy(rotVector).applyAxisAngle(axis, angleStep * i);
  scene.add(mesh);
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```